# compute the word coverage for the given fileid associated with text corpus inagurual using nltk

Tags: python, text, nltk, corpus, calculated-field

I Have tried the below code.#!/bin/python3

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import zipfile
import nltk


#
# Complete the 'accessTextCorpora' function below.
#
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. STRING fileid
#  2. STRING word
#
from nltk.corpus import inaugural
def accessTextCorpora(fileid, word):
    for fileid in inaugural.fileids():
        total_words = len(inaugural.words(fileid))
        total_unique_words = len(set(inaugural.words(fileid)))
        wordcoverage  = int(total_words / total_unique_words)
        ed_words = [word for word in set(inaugural.words(fileid)) if word.endswith('ed')]
        textfreq2 = [word.lower() for word in inaugural.words(fileid) if word.isalpha()]
        textfreq = nltk.FreqDist(textfreq2)
        wordfreq = textfreq[word]
        return wordcoverage, ed_words, wordfreq
```

It is passing only one test case. Remaining all test cases showing the same result. Could you please suggest me what i need to change.

These are the outputs.

```
TestCase 0:

Input (stdin)
Run as Custom Input
|
Download
1789-Washington.txt
government
```

**Your Output (stdout)**
2
['United', 'accomplished', 'addressed', 'advanced', 'affected', 'allotted', 'assembled', 'awakened', 'called', 'committed', 'compared', 'considered', 'consulted', 'contemplated', 'delegated', 'departed', 'derived', 'distinguished', 'employed', 'enlarged', 'entrusted', 'established', 'exemplified', 'expected', 'experienced', 'filled', 'forced', 'fortified', 'guided', 'honored', 'imparted', 'included', 'instituted', 'judged', 'limited', 'ordained', 'originated', 'palliated', 'persuaded', 'placed', 'pleased', 'produced', 'promoted', 'received', 'rendered', 'repaired', 'required', 'resulted', 'sacred', 'selected', 'staked', 'submitted', 'summoned', 'suppressed', 'swayed', 'transmitted', 'united', 'unparalleled', 'unpracticed', 'untried', 'urged']
8

**Expected Output**
Download
2
['United', 'accomplished', 'addressed', 'advanced', 'affected', 'allotted', 'assembled', 'awakened', 'called', 'committed', 'compared', 'considered', 'consulted', 'contemplated', 'delegated', 'departed', 'derived', 'distinguished', 'employed', 'enlarged', 'entrusted', 'established', 'exemplified', 'expected', 'experienced', 'filled', 'forced', 'fortified', 'guided', 'honored', 'imparted', 'included', 'instituted', 'judged', 'limited', 'ordained', 'originated', 'palliated', 'persuaded', 'placed', 'pleased', 'produced', 'promoted', 'received', 'rendered', 'repaired', 'required', 'resulted', 'sacred', 'selected', 'staked', 'submitted', 'summoned', 'suppressed', 'swayed', 'transmitted', 'united', 'unparalleled', 'unpracticed', 'untried', 'urged']
8

TestCase1:

**Input (stdin)
Run as Custom Input**
|

1793-Washington.txt
i

**Your Output (stdout)**
2
['United', 'accomplished', 'addressed', 'advanced', 'affected', 'allotted', 'assembled', 'awakened', 'called', 'committed', 'compared', 'considered', 'consulted', 'contemplated', 'delegated', 'departed', 'derived', 'distinguished', 'employed', 'enlarged', 'entrusted', 'established', 'exemplified', 'expected', 'experienced', 'filled', 'forced', 'fortified', 'guided', 'honored', 'imparted', 'included', 'instituted', 'judged', 'limited', 'ordained', 'originated', 'palliated', 'persuaded', 'placed', 'pleased', 'produced', 'promoted', 'received', 'rendered', 'repaired', 'required', 'resulted', 'sacred', 'selected', 'staked', 'submitted', 'summoned', 'suppressed', 'swayed', 'transmitted', 'united', 'unparalleled', 'unpracticed', 'untried', 'urged']
23

**Expected Output**

1
['called', 'distinguished', 'reposed', 'united', 'violated']
6

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 'for' loop as looping is not required. The function has parameters that will be computed.

Answer (score 1):

use for fileidi in inaugural fileids because it read all the files instead of only one.

Comment: What was the mistake he was doing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please don't use for loop and fileid is already provided.
2. for ed_words, use set to get unique words.

```py
    import math
    import os
    import random
    import re
    import sys
    import zipfile
    import nltk

    from nltk.corpus import inaugural
    def accessTextCorpora(fileid, word):
        # Write your code here
        file_words = inaugural.words(fileid)
        wordcoverage = int(len(file_words)/len(set(file_words)))
        ed_words = [words for words in set(file_words) if words.endswith('ed')]
        textfreq2 = [word.lower() for word in file_words if word.isalpha()]
        textfreq = nltk.FreqDist(textfreq2)
        wordfreq = textfreq[word]
    
        return wordcoverage, ed_words, wordfreq
```

Thanks.